# How to open a POP3 folder programmatically

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3

I am on the way to write a little mailserver in Java without JavaMail library. Until now i always used netcat to test and debug it like

```
nc pop.domain.com 110
helo
user <myname>
pass <mypass>
list
```

and so on and everything worked. Now i have tried Outlook Mail Client and also have tried to connect my GMail account to see if that also works but it fails :S The login procedure is working in both (gmail and outlook) but when it comes to LIST, CAPA or RETR, it doesnt work. Now i used another java script that uses Java Mail API and have tried to retrieve messages but recognized the Java error "folder is not open" when i issuing

```
folder = store.getDefaultFolder().getFolder("INBOX");
```

So how can i "open" it and tell the POP client that the folder is open?

greetz

**EDIT:** i think the solution is the same like respond to TOP. I tried with outlook mail client and it works when i respond

```
+OK <messagecount> (<foldersice> octets)
#<MSG_ID>
<MSG_SUBJECT>
#<MSG_ID>
<MSG_SUBJECT>
#<MSG_ID>
<MSG_SUBJECT>
// and so on
```

Comment: [POP3]() has no concept of "folders" and POP4 never came into existence. You are asking for the folder `INBOX` below the default folder, which POP3 cannot handle. Either remove the `getDefaultFolder().` or the `getFolder("INBOX")`.

Comment: Please see my question, i use the linked script and it works in other situations.

Comment: In the linked code, you call `getFolder("INBOX")` on the store directly. In the question you call `getFolder("INBOX")` on the return value from `getDefaultFolder()`. But POP3 probably ignores all of that, anyway, so it might not be your problem.

Comment: Why should the function openFolder() exist if there is no concept of folders.. thats curious

Comment: The JavaMail message [`Store`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Store.html) is built around mail folders. [`POP3Store`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/POP3Store.html) is documented to offer only a single virtual "INBOX" folder. As for why, I can only guess, but probably because it would hurt more to make it optional.

Comment: doesnt it mean that there is a function (or request code) and therefore a folder function must execute and return something (response code). i thought all popular mail protocols are text based. like in imap OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed indicates, that the folder is writeable.

Comment: Well, there's [`STAT`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1939#page-6), but there's simply no concept of a "folder" other than the "mailbox" in POP3. The JavaMail API shows the single POP3 mailbox as a single "INBOX" folder, but the protocol has no folder concept.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you've read **none** of the documentation...  :-(

How about the [Folder.open](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#open-int-) method?

Before asking your next question, read the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).

Comment: No, you misunderstood! I have read it! I want to write the other part. When i am the SERVER and someone is issuing Folder.open() inside a java mail programm to my server - what should i respond to tell him he can read the messages??

Comment: of course i did! but didnt found a description for exacly that, maybe you can lead me?

Comment: I must not understand what you're trying to do.  Are you implementing your own POP3 server?  If so, once the client authenticates, the folder should be open.  There's no special POP3 command to open the folder.  How you open the folder depends entirely on how you're implementing your POP3 server.  Maybe the folder is a file?  Maybe the folder is a database?  It's up to you.  If that doesn't help, explain in more detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, you understand me :D Yes i try to write my own without libraries. I switched over to imap now because i found an exact protocol flow therefore https://blogs.oracle.com/jhawk/entry/obtaining_email_quota_from_imap but also want to implement pop later. But there must be a response code am i wrong? If not how do the client know if there are mails and how much data will come?

Comment: Writing your own IMAP server is a **HUGE** job.  You're going to need to read the [IMAP spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501) at least 5 times to have any hope of getting it right.  Trying to write an IMAP server by looking at IMAP protocol examples is doomed to failure if you want it to actually be __correct__ instead of just __good enough__.

Comment: I just want to enlarge my coding experience so its ok :D But i know what you mean, now i try to parse UID Commands correctly.. thats bad! :D

Comment: Please read the spec carefully, which describes the syntax of all commands in precise detail.  If you can't figure out how to read the syntax descriptions in the spec, you shouldn't be doing this!

Comment: its also useful to know how to read specs. So maybe i can learn something that i havent learned until now at school or work.